# Refreshing when answering questions on Stack Exchange can save a draft?

Tags: discussion

I accidentally refreshed when I'am answering a question. Can that save a draft?

Comment: How about if I closed the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on rene's comment, Stack Exchange saves a draft when you refreshed normally. I'am not sure if mobile devices can do the same thing.

Well, I converted rene's comment to an answer because it is really an answer to that question.